# How to secure a contact form in PHP

Tags: php

I'm not php savvy, can someone please provide a good strong code that I can use tailored for my form to prevent injections into my script? I would need to know exactly where to insert this code within my existing code.

My code is below. I left off the opening and ending php tags so all of the code would be visible.

```
$name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
$website=addslashes($_POST['website']);
$services=addslashes($_POST['services']);
$comments=addslashes($_POST['message']);

// you can specify which email you want your contact form to be emailed to here

$toemail = "email@domainname.com"; $subject = "Creative Design Consultation Request";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ."From: \"".$name."\" <".$email.">\n" ."Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

$body = "Name: ".$name."\n"
."Email: ".$email."\n"
."Website: ".$website."\n"
."Services: ".$services."\n"
."Comments:\n".$comments;

mail($toemail, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo "Thank you for submitting your request";
```

Comment: You are not StackOverflow savvy either, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask questions here. Simply asking for code isn't really how things work here.

Comment: What you are looking for is generally called "input sanitization"

Comment: Thank you Antony, you're right, just because I've been struggling with just the form part for the past two days doesn't excuse me from taking the time to learn the ins and out of proper communication on this exchange. Pardon me please, I meant no offense, and yes, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Hi @Extrakun, yes, you're right. There is more than one way to do it and I don't know how to take any one of them and custom it for my form.

Comment: look into prepared statements.  sorry I'm to tired to point you anywhere useful.  good luck

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for:
[Sanitize filters php](http://php.net/manual/it/filter.filters.sanitize.php)